# Question about nickname functionality

Tags: html

Does this work or not? I am not sure if this is how it works.

Will this make sense if I just add the   tag line before I implement wordpress.  I am having a major problem with this.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange. Your question doesn't seem to have enough information for what you want to do. Are you just looking for the purpose of SPBuiltInField.Nickname?

I will attempt to answer your question presuming the above:

Nickname is just a field "*Identifies a field that contains the informal name of a person who is referenced in a specified SharePoint Foundation contact object.*" [[source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.nickname.aspx)] This fields purpose is to allow other people to search for the user by their known name, as well as their real name and phonetic name spellings.

So if someone's name is "Robert" their Nickname maybe "Bob".

It's a tool to help people find one another.